# WPF Custom Control derived from ItemsControl fails to display bound data

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I've created a custom control called MovableItemsControl, inheriting from ItemsControl, in order to override the *GetContainerForItemOverride()* method. My problem is that none of the objects in the bound collection are displaying. Currently, I'm binding to an OberservableCollection of strings, and I can see that they're in *ItemsSource* when I look through the debugger.

The custom control is shown below:

```
public class MovableItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    static MovableItemsControl()
    {          
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MovableItemsControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MovableItemsControl)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps each content object added to the ItemsControl in a NodeWrapper
    /// </summary>
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        NodeWrapper nodeWrapper = new NodeWrapper();            
        return nodeWrapper;
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is NodeWrapper;
    }
}
```

NodeWrapper is a UserControl consisting of a custom control derived from Thumb (MoveThumb) and a Label (the Label is just for testing).

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MovableItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MovableItemsControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you created the default Style for MoveableItemsControl with a ControlTemplate in the Generic.xaml file of the project containing the control? If not, there's nothing for the control to render when it loads.

**UPDATE**
The ControlTemplate for an ItemsControl needs to contain an ItemsPresenter as a placeholder for the items to be injected (similar to ContentPresenter for ContentControl). Your current template only has an empty Border.

Comment: I have created a default style. I've edited it into my question:

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing inside your style ControlTemplate Border either:
a) An ItemPresenter (eg `<ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>`) OR
b) A pannel with IsItemsHost set true (eg `<StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>`)